# Is there any option to remove uploaded file in Primefaces fileupload?

Tags: file-upload, primefaces

Do we have any option to remove/delete option in Fileupload in prime faces. Because if, we uploaded a file by mistake how can we remove that file from the attachments? I think primefaces are intelligent enough to give this option. If not do we have any other way to do it?

Regards
Bhanu Teja M.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, primeface Fileupload does provide that intelligent option. Therefore, you should **not** use temporary folder(`<init-param><param-name>uploadDirectory</param-name><param-value>/Users/primefaces/temp</param-value></init-param>`), but you should implement the logic to save the file
contents yourself at your backing bean.